# objective c how to add frame (image) on captured video file

Tags: video-editing

i am developing an app that capture video then user select frame (imagefile) then save mixed video (frame over the video ) in cameraroll, but i dont know how to mixup that thing....? please Help Me!!!
give me some example code

thanx in advance